# Making a dropdown menu in Flutter with a Map

Tags: dictionary, drop-down-menu, dart, flutter

so i'm wanting to create an object in flutter that takes a `Map<String, int>` as a list of values, where the `String` is what is displayed in the menu, and the `int` is stored inside the class for later usage after an item is selected.

i am unsure how to do this. the part involving returning the `int` value eludes me.

the map structure is written like this:

```
  final Map<String, int> discBasis = {
    'Age': 1,
    'Ancestry': 2,
    'Color': 3,
    'Disability': 4,
    'Race': 5,
    'Religion': 6,
    'Sex': 7,
    'Familial Status': 8,
    'National Origin': 9
  };
```

& the class which i am currently using:

```
final double formMarginHoriz = 10.0;
final double formMarginVert = 5.0;

class DropDownFromMap extends StatefulWidget {
  Map<String, int> kv;
  DropDownFromMap(this.kv);

  @override
  DropDownFromMapState createState() => new DropDownFromMapState(kv);
}

class DropDownFromMapState extends State<DropDownFromMap> {
  Map<String, int> kv;
  DropDownFromMapState(this.kv);

  int selectedVal;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
            top: formMarginVert,
            bottom: formMarginVert,
            left: formMarginVert,
            right: formMarginHoriz),
        child: new DropdownButton<int>(
          hint: new Text("Select an option"),
          value: selectedVal,
          onChanged: (String newVal) {
            setState(() {
              selectedVal = kv[newVal];
            });
          },
          items: kv.map((String k, _) {
            return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: k,
              child: new Text(k),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ));
  }
}
```

and it is instantiated like this (this is probably wrong):

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Material(
        color: Colors.blueAccent,
        child: new Container(
            child: new Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: new Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new DropDownFromMap(data.offenderType),
...
```

more context can be found at the github project: https://github.com/chscodeforchange/icrc-app in the relevant files: `dropdown.dart`, `off_page_one.dart`, & `form_data.dart`.

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 19):

```
static const Map<String, Duration> frequencyOptions = {
    "30 seconds": Duration(seconds: 30),
    "1 minute": Duration(minutes: 1),
    "2 minutes": Duration(minutes: 2),
  };

Duration _frequencyValue = Duration(seconds: 30);

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<Duration>(
          items: frequencyOptions
              .map((description, value) {
                return MapEntry(
                    description,
                    DropdownMenuItem<Duration>(
                      value: value,
                      child: Text(description),
                    ));
              })
              .values
              .toList(),
          value: _frequencyValue,
          onChanged: (Duration? newValue) {
            if (newValue != null) {
              setState(() {
                _frequencyValue = newValue;
              });
            }
          },
        );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Instead of using Map use this,

```
final List<DropdownMenuItem> list = [
DropdownMenuItem(value: "", child: Container((...your widget style), child: Text("Select"))),
DropdownMenuItem(value: "value1", child: Container((...your widget style), child: Text("title1"))),
DropdownMenuItem(value: "value2", child: Container((...your widget style), child: Text("title2")))
];

DropdownButton(
              value: "",
              items: list,
              onChanged: (value) {},
            ),
```

with this you could use your own variations. I thought this was the best way for me as I had to hard code just two or three items to show up in the dropdown. You can create a seperate Model and use this idea to generate any type of dropdown list with map.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see anything wrong with your code except is that you need to remove the constructor and the map in the `State` object, and only leave the ones inside the `StatefulWidget` itself. You can access your map then by using `widget.kv`